# what is this annotation in jquery validator plugin line 86

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

hi i am using jquery validator plugin , i saw annnotation like this

```
|=
```

what does this mean , i have never seen like that ,

this is code

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid
valid: function() {
if ( $(this[0]).is('form')) {
    return this.validate().form();
} else {
    var valid = false;
    var validator = $(this[0].form).validate();
    this.each(function() {
            valid |= validator.element(this);
    });
    return valid;
}
```

},

please help....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var1 |= var2;
```

is the same as

```
var1 = var1 | var2;
```

`|` is the bitwise OR operator

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Some examples of ORing numbers:

```
1 | 1 => 1
1 | 2 => 3
1 | 3 => 3    
1 | 4 => 5
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a BitWise OR assignment operator

Similar to doing `x = x | y`, it's the shorthand of that, `x |= y`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators